# Avoiding CS1718 "Comparison made to the same variable" in test

Tags: c#

In general, code of the form `x == x` will trigger compiler warning [CS1718](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1718) "Comparison made to same variable; did you mean to compare something else?"

That's usually good and sensible, but one case where one might actually *want* a check of this form is if a given type overrides `operator==` and one wants a test asserting that indeed `x == x`. Is there a good way around this (noting that alternatives like `Assert.Equal(x, x)` won't cut it since we explicitly want `operator==`), or is one stuck with explicitly disabling the warning through expressions like

```cs
            ...
#pragma warning disable CS1718 // Comparison made to same variable
            Assert.True(x == x);
#pragma warning restore CS1718 // Comparison made to same variable
            ...
```

Comment: `var y=x; Assert.True(y==x);`?

Comment: Why isn't the pragma exactly the right answer to this?  The expression you have is exactly the wording you want.

Comment: If you find yourself doing a lot of these kinds of tests, add `1718` to the `NoWarn` property in the unit test project. Then you don't need individual pragmas peppered throughout.

Comment: Put the `#pragma warning disable` at the top of your file, leave out the `restore`, done. You are hardly going to be doing this accidentally in a file dedicated to testing this specific scenario. If for some reason you absolute must have a single expression for this and you can't use `#pragma` ("don't want to" is not a good enough reason) `Assert.True(x == (_ = x))` would do, using a discard -- with the significant drawback that it doesn't look like what you want it to mean.